# Automate installation SqlJobs SqlServer

Tags: sql-server

Is there a way to install SqlJobs on SqlServer by a script? I would like the sqljobs to be installed when setting up a Database remotely at a customer. Is this possible?

Comment: Hmm. I'm actually trying to increase views on this question. I don't think mine is a great answer, and I'd love to help you more, if you'd provide better info, or others would weigh in with comments/answers.

Comment: Well, better info, what do you mean? Now I need to deploy databases on remote servers, and I would like to add these jobs to our continuous integration. We have a Database Version Control system that automatically executes update scripts and changes to sps and functions. Would like to add those sqljobs too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're meaning to add SQL Agent jobs, you need only look as far as the sp_add_job(step|schedule|server) stored procedures in msdb, which are reasonably well described in [BOL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182079.aspx)

If, on the other hand, you're talking about ensuring the the agent is installed, running, etc. then I do not believe there is a way to do this via script.

If, on the third hand, you're talking about some particular product/database, when talking about SQLJobs, then this answer won't help you at all.

*Edit*

And the easiest way to get the right invocations (again, if we're talking SQL Agent jobs) is to build them on your local machine, then script them through SSMS/EM. Biggest gotcha I've found is you need to add a server to a job, even if it's only ever intended to be a local server job.

*Edit 2*

In response to first comment - your call to sp_add_jobserver can specify the server name as '(Local)', which will make it a local server job.

Here's a short but complete (and hopefully still working) script that automates restoring a database overnight. Notice that it makes no reference to which server it's on, so will add the job to whatever server it's being run against:

```
USE [msdb]
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION
DECLARE @ReturnCode INT
SELECT @ReturnCode = 0
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT name FROM msdb.dbo.syscategories WHERE name=N'Database Maintenance' AND category_class=1)
BEGIN
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_category @class=N'JOB', @type=N'LOCAL', @name=N'Database Maintenance'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

END

DECLARE @jobId BINARY(16)
EXEC @ReturnCode =  msdb.dbo.sp_add_job @job_name=N'RESTORE_DatabaseN', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @notify_level_eventlog=2, 
        @notify_level_email=0, 
        @notify_level_netsend=0, 
        @notify_level_page=0, 
        @delete_level=0, 
        @description=N'No description available.', 
        @category_name=N'Database Maintenance', 
        @owner_login_name=N'sa', @job_id = @jobId OUTPUT
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobstep @job_id=@jobId, @step_name=N'step 1', 
        @step_id=1, 
        @cmdexec_success_code=0, 
        @on_success_action=3, 
        @on_success_step_id=0, 
        @on_fail_action=2, 
        @on_fail_step_id=0, 
        @retry_attempts=0, 
        @retry_interval=1, 
        @os_run_priority=0, @subsystem=N'TSQL', 
        @command=N'DECLARE @BakFile varchar(120),  
        @OLD_DB sysname,
        @NEW_DB sysname,
        @RestoreData sysname,
        @RestoreLog sysname,
        @DBLogical varchar(255),
        @LogLogical varchar(255),

SET @OLD_DB     = ''DatabaseN''
SET @NEW_DB      = ''DatabaseN''
SET @BakFile = ''\\remoteserver\Backups\Server2\DatabaseN\DatabaseN.BAK''

SET @RestoreData = ''E:\sqldata\'' + @NEW_DB + ''.mdf''
SET @RestoreLog  = ''F:\SQLLogs\'' + @NEW_DB + ''_log.ldf''

create table #filelist (LogicalName varchar(255), PhysicalName varchar(255), Type varchar(20), FileGroupName varchar(255), Size varchar(20), MaxSize varchar(20) )
insert #filelist exec (''RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM disk = '''''' + @BakFile +  '''''''')
select @DBLogical = LogicalName from #filelist where Type = ''D''
select @LogLogical = LogicalName from #filelist where Type = ''L''

RESTORE DATABASE @NEW_DB FROM DISK = @BakFile
WITH MOVE @DBLogical TO @RestoreData,
MOVE @LogLogical TO @RestoreLog, REPLACE
EXEC ('' USE '' + @NEW_DB + '' BACKUP LOG '' + @NEW_DB + '' WITH Truncate_Only'')

EXEC ('' USE '' + @NEW_DB + '' ALTER DATABASE '' + @NEW_DB + '' SET RECOVERY SIMPLE'')

--EXEC ('' USE '' + @NEW_DB + '' dbcc shrinkfile('' + @LogLogical + '', 2000)'')
', 
        @database_name=N'master', 
        @flags=0
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback

EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_update_job @job_id = @jobId, @start_step_id = 1
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobschedule @job_id=@jobId, @name=N'daily', 
        @enabled=1, 
        @freq_type=8, 
        @freq_interval=127, 
        @freq_subday_type=1, 
        @freq_subday_interval=0, 
        @freq_relative_interval=0, 
        @freq_recurrence_factor=1, 
        @active_start_date=20070708, 
        @active_end_date=99991231, 
        @active_start_time=11500, 
        @active_end_time=235959
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
EXEC @ReturnCode = msdb.dbo.sp_add_jobserver @job_id = @jobId, @server_name = N'(local)'
IF (@@ERROR <> 0 OR @ReturnCode <> 0) GOTO QuitWithRollback
COMMIT TRANSACTION
GOTO EndSave
QuitWithRollback:
    IF (@@TRANCOUNT > 0) ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
EndSave:

GO
```

Comment: Indeed, adding the server to a job is the thing that messes up everything. I need to deploy the jobs on different servers.